# I keep getting an exception in main error after i enter my first array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, boolean, compare

For some reason I am getting the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
    at IdenticalArrays.main(IdenticalArrays.java:28)

/*
 * Class:       CS 2301/08
 * Term:        Fall 2014
 * Name:        Clarence E. Hollins III
 * Instructor:  Rashad Jones
 * Assignment:  4
 */
 //Create a program that receives two strings from the user and prints whether or not they are identical

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class IdenticalArrays
{
   public static void main(String [] Args)
  {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



     System.out.println("Enter list: ");
     String s = input.nextLine();
     char sizeofArray = s.charAt(0);

     int size = (int)sizeofArray; 

     int[] firstList = new int [size];
        for(int i = 0; i < firstList.length; i++)
           {
              firstList[i] = s.charAt(i+1);
           }



     System.out.println("Please enter list 2: ");
     int[] secondList = new int[size];

           for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
              {
                 secondList[i] = s.charAt(i+1);
              } 


              boolean status = equals(firstList, secondList);
     if(status == true)


     System.out.println("The first list is: " + firstList.length + " " + firstList);
     System.out.println("The second list is: " + secondList.length + " " + secondList);

  }

   public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2)
  {

     Arrays.sort(list1);
     Arrays.sort(list2);

     for(int i = 0; i < list1.length && i < list2.length; i++)
     {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i])
        {
                        return false;
        } 
     }
     return true;

  }      
}
```

Comment: Why is your `sizeOfArray` variable of type `char`?

Comment: `s.charAt(i+1)` seems to be your problem...I don't think you want to use `s.charAt(0)` to determine the size of the list, more you want to use `s.length()`...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be 100% sure, but, if you're going to do...

```
char sizeofArray = s.charAt(0);
```

And then...

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstList.length; i++) {
    firstList[i] = s.charAt(i + 1);
```

You will want to reduce the number of loops by 1, as you've taken the first character out of the `String`

Now, you could use `String#subString` to reduce the input by one character or you could simply reduce the number of iterations by one...

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstList.length - 1; i++) {
    firstList[i] = s.charAt(i + 1);
```

This will go for your second loop as well

Now, having said that, given the fact that you are basically ignoring the `size` value anyway, you should probably do something more like...

```
    //char sizeofArray = s.charAt(0);
    int size = s.length();

    int[] firstList = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        firstList[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }
```

Mind you, based on the requirements...

> Create a program that receives two strings from the user and prints whether or not they are identical

Something like `String#equals(String)` would be a quicker solution...;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) like

```
char[] firstList = s.toCharArray();
```

If those characters are supposed to be digits, you could do

```
char[] firstList = s.toCharArray();
int[] digits = new int[firstList.length];
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    digits[i] = Character.digit(firstList[i], 10);
}
```

Finally, to test if two `int` arrays are equal you can use [`Arrays.equals(int[],int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int[],%20int[]%29).